# how to transfer array of objects from controller to viewer codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

So here is my code in controller:

```
public function logged_in()
{
    if($this->input->post('log_out'))
    {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('username');
        redirect(base_url()."main_c");
    }

    if(!$this->session->userdata('username'))
    {
        redirect(base_url()."main_c/login");
    }

    $this->load->model('main_m');

    $data = $this->main_m->get_user();



    $this->load->view('logged_in_v', $data);


}
```

and here is my model code:

```
public function get_user()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('user');


    return $query->result();



}
```

So basically what I want to do is to make a loop in viewer and output every single object which are in $data. So my question is: How to transfer array in viewer to make my viewer look something like this:

```
    foreach($data as $ob)
    {
        echo "username: ".$ob->username." ";
        echo "password: ".$ob->password;
        echo "</br>";
    }
```

Comment: Did you looked at codeigniter view documentation.please look at here https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller code should be :

```
public function logged_in()
{
    if($this->input->post('log_out'))
    {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('username');
        redirect(base_url()."main_c");
    }

    if(!$this->session->userdata('username'))
    {
        redirect(base_url()."main_c/login");
    }

    $this->load->model('main_m');

    $data['data'] = $this->main_m->get_user();



    $this->load->view('logged_in_v', $data);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this in the controller-->

```
$this->load->model('main_m');

$data['users'] = $this->main_m->get_user();

$this->load->view('logged_in_v', $data);
```

And then in the view-->

```
foreach($users as $ob)
{
    echo "username: ".$ob->username." ";
    echo "password: ".$ob->password;
    echo "</br>";
}
```